# Does $\liminf_{r\to 0+} f'(r) \geq 0$ implies the existence of $f(0 +)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real-valued differentiable function on $(0,1)$, and suppose that
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{0<r<1} |f(r)| < \infty, 
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\liminf_{r \to 0+} \,f'(r) \geq 0.
\end{equation*}
Can we conclude that $f(0+)$ exists?

Comment: For one, what's $f(0+)$? It's not notation that's particularly common. I would guess that it is $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)$. Second, "suppose that $\sup_{0<r<1} |f(r)| < \infty$" can be more simply written as "suppose $f$ is bounded".

Comment: Am I missing something or is $\sin(1/x)$ a counter-example?

Comment: @Thorgott No, the $\lim \inf$ of the derivative of that is $-\infty$.

Comment: If you consider $f'$ you are thus assuming $f$ is differentiable over $(0,1)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that the $\lim\inf$ is taken of the derivative; I thought it was a limit of the function itself.

Comment: @Thorgott Then it would still be wrong, since $\liminf \sin \frac{1}{x} = -1 < 0$

Comment: Oh yeah... Though that could be taken care of by using the absolute value.

Comment: If you intend $f$ to be differentiable in $(0,1),$ you should say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $g(r)= r+f(r).$ Then $g'(r)> 0$ for $r$ in some $(0,a).$

Comment: Thanks @zhw. It is very clear now

Answer (score 0):

Your first condition says $f$ is bounded on $(0,1)$.

Case I:    $\underset{r \rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim inf}} f'(r)>0$

In this case the lim inf condition says that eventually, for some $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small, $f'$ is positive on $(0,\epsilon)$, which means $f$ is increasing on $(0,\epsilon)$.

$f$ bounded and increasing on $(0,\epsilon)$ implies $f(0+):= \underset{r\rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim }} f(r) = \underset{r\in(0,\epsilon)}{\inf}f(r) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Case II:    $\underset{r \rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim inf }} f'(r)=0$

Put $g(r):=r+f(r)$

So $g'(r)=1+f'(r) \Rightarrow \underset{r \rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim inf }} g'(r)= 1 + \underset{r \rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim inf }} f'(r)=1>0$

Again, the lim inf condition says that eventually, for some $a>0$ sufficiently small, $g'$ is positive on $(0,a)$, which means $g$ is increasing on $(0,a)$.

Note $g$ is also bounded on $(0,1)$.

$g$ bounded and increasing on $(0,a)$ implies $g(0+):= \underset{r\rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim }} g(r) = \underset{r\in(0,a)}{\inf}g(r) \in \mathbb{R}$.

But also $g(0+):= \underset{r\rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim }} g(r) =  \underset{r\rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim }} (r+f(r))- \underset{r\rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim }} r= \underset{r\rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim }} f(r) = f(0+)$.

Comment: yes ... thanks zhw ... with your hint it was easy to figure out what to do with the = in the second condition

Answer (score -1):

Your first condition says $f$ is bounded on $(0,1)$.

Case I:    $\underset{r \rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim inf}} f'(r)>0$

In this case the lim inf condition says that eventually, for some $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small, $f'$ is positive on $(0,\epsilon)$, which means $f$ is increasing on $(0,\epsilon)$.

$f$ bounded and increasing on $(0,\epsilon)$ implies $f(0+):= \underset{r\rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim }} f(r) = \underset{r\in(0,\epsilon)}{\inf}f(r) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Case II:    $\underset{r \rightarrow 0+}{\text{lim inf}} f'(r)=0$

...

(It is not clear to me whether $f(0+)$ exists in this case.)

Comment: This is a non-answer. You're just imposing a stronger condition, namely $>$ rather than $\geq$.

Comment: Despite MathematicsStudent1122 quick dismissal of my answer, it does show the answer to the original question is "yes" whenever the lim inf f'(r) is strictly positive.  It remains to just show/ focus on what happens when the lim inf f'(r) =0 (i.e. Case II).